# How to make webmachine play nice with websockets?

Tags: erlang, websocket, real-time, webmachine

Webmachine seems like a great system to build REST web services, but I know it does not provide websocket compatibility. My question is rather straightforward : **What would be a good approach to add websocket capabilities on top of a web service built with webmachine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running [Misultin](https://github.com/ostinelli/misultin) alongside Webmachine for that exact matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, it looks great! For the records, the project on google code is discontinued, but development continues on [github](https://github.com/ostinelli/misultin).

Comment: Also the latest commits can handle the most recent versions of websockets.

Answer (score 0):

For easy use websockets in webmachine I implemented that by changing sources of webmachine (adding support mochiweb_websockets ) and mochiweb (add support secure websockets).

You can download from git full solution (webmachine with websockets support) by this link:
https://github.com/Dryymoon/webmachine.git

And by this link example usage of solution.

Or if want dig a little deeper:
I changed only two files of sources:
1) webmachine_decision_core.erl changed (add support websocket handler).
2) mochiweb_websocket.erl (add support secure websockets and patch existig).

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but just stumbled upon this, but another option is to run SimpleBridge (https://github.com/nitrogen/simple_bridge), which adds an abstraction layer (conditionally bypassed using webmachines routing system) which adds websocket support to any erlang webserver it supports (includes webmachine).